# How to draw points of a sphere in a cubic environment?

Tags: python

Given a center point `(x0, y0, z0)` and a radius (`g_radius`)
I want to use Python to generate points in a sphere in a cubic world (= Minecraft).

I'm trying to use this algorithm (I found it here on so) but it's not precise and I have to increase the number of samples to a ridiculous huge number to get almost all the points, but it's still not 100% accurate:

```
num_pts = 10000000
indices = arange(0, num_pts, dtype=float) + 0.5
phi = arccos(1 - 2 * indices / num_pts)
theta = pi * (1 + 5 ** 0.5) * indices
t_x, t_y, t_z = cos(theta) * sin(phi), sin(theta) * sin(phi), cos(phi)
tmp = [(g_x0 + int(x * g_radius),
        g_y0 + int(y * g_radius) + g_radius,
        g_z0 + int(z * g_radius))
       for (x, y, z) in zip(t_x, t_y, t_z)]
final_coord_result = list(set(tmp))
```

Here's what you get with a small radius (`5`):

[image: minecraft sphere]

How would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [raster_geometry](https://github.com/norok2/raster_geometry):

[image]

```py
import raster_geometry
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# define degree of rasterization
radius = 7.5

# create full sphere
sphere_coords = raster_geometry.sphere(int(2*radius), radius)
# make it hollow
sphere_coords = raster_geometry.unfill(sphere_coords)

# plot it
ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(*sphere_coords.nonzero())
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but how to get an array of points (`x`,`y`,`y`) like the final line in my code: `final_coord_result = list(set(tmp))`

Comment: that should be possible via `np.nonzero()` as well, i.e. `x, y, z = sphere_coords.nonzero()`

Comment: It worked, watch this: https://youtu.be/ZGv4F0FBLKY

Comment: that's no moon.... it's a work of art!